# "No such index" error in ElasticSearch controller when loading custom module

Tags: elasticsearch, sugarcrm

I had created a bunch of custom `modules` bundled in a single package on a SugarCRM 8.0.0 staging instance. In order to migrate these `modules` I decided to `publish` the package so that I could have an installable zip uploaded to another instance. Unfortunately when I try to upload the zip file on the receiving instance using module loader, the installation hangs at 80 percent gives an error in the sugarlog

I am running `ElasticSearch 5.4` which is compatible with the instance of the Sugar I am running. This is the error that is shown in the logs:

```
Thu Mar 28 17:54:19 2019 [1786][1][FATAL] Elasticsearch request failure: no such index [index: ab164c0013004724c8eba5f5f6f3f646_shared]
Thu Mar 28 17:54:19 2019 [1786][1][FATAL] Exception in Controller: Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: no such index [index: ab164c0013004724c8eba5f5f6f3f646_shared] in /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php:179
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Request.php(193): Elastica\Transport\Http->exec(Object(Elastica\Request), Array)
#1 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(674): Elastica\Request->send()
#2 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/src/Elasticsearch/Adapter/Client.php(355): Elastica\Client->request('ab164c001300472...', 'PUT', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(706): Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Adapter\Client->request('ab164c001300472...', 'PUT', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Index.php(562): Elastica\Client->requestEndpoint(Object(Elasticsearch\Endpoints\Indices\Mapping\Put))
#5 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Type.php(523): Elastica\Index->requestEndpoint(Object(Elasticsearch\Endpoints\Indices\Mapping\Put))
#6 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Type/Mapping.php(250): Elastica\Type->requestEndpoint(Object(Elasticsearch\Endpoints\Indices\Mapping\Put))
#7 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/src/Elasticsearch/Index/IndexManager.php(486): Elastica\Type\Mapping->send()
#8 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/src/Elasticsearch/Index/IndexManager.php(390): Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Index\IndexManager->sendMapping(Object(Elastica\Type\Mapping))
#9 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/src/Elasticsearch/Index/IndexManager.php(285): Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Index\IndexManager->createIndices(Object(Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Index\IndexCollection), Object(Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Analysis\AnalysisBuilder), Object(Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Mapping\MappingCollection), false)
#10 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/src/Elasticsearch/Index/IndexManager.php(200): Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Index\IndexManager->syncIndices(Array, false)
#11 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/src/SearchEngine/Engine/Elastic.php(113): Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Elasticsearch\Index\IndexManager->addMappings(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php(3489): Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\SearchEngine\Engine\Elastic->addMappings(Array)
#13 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php(168): ModuleInstaller->setup_elastic_mapping()
#14 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/modules/Administration/UpgradeWizard_commit.php(342): ModuleInstaller->install('cache/upgrades/...')
#15 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php(489): require_once('/var/www/html/S...')
#16 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/include/MVC/View/views/view.classic.php(43): SugarView->includeClassicFile('cache/upgrades/...')
#17 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php(152): ViewClassic->display(Array)
#18 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php(351): SugarView->process(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php(299): SugarController->processView()
#20 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/include/MVC/SugarApplication.php(198): SugarController->execute()
#21 /var/www/html/SugarPro-Full-8/index.php(27): SugarApplication->execute()
#22 {main}
Thu Mar 28 17:54:19 2019 [1786][1][FATAL] ERROR: rmdir_recursive(): argument cache/upgrades/temp/ICB8l3 is not a file or a dir.
```

I have tried to repair and rebuild several times, and have also tried to publish the package again to recheck if there were any errors I may have not noticed. I tried to use another instance for uploading in case my current instance may be corrupt, but the same was observed. I do not understand what may be causing the issue.

Comment: have you tried to reset permission using the command line?

Comment: Yes, I've reset the permissions as well as restarted several times

Comment: @noobdev Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @Jay apologies for the late reply, I had tried your solution, but unfortunately shows me a "memory exhausted" error when I hit `save`

Comment: Is your php's memory limit set to 512 MB?   see https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/8.0/Pro/Administration_Guide/Advanced_Configuration_Options/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Elasticsearch request failure: no such index [index: ...]
```

This suggests that the Elasticsearch Index is missing (or corrupted).

**How to fix:**

- Log-on to Sugar with admin privileges
- Go to ***Administration* -> *Search*** (or *Global Search* in some versions of Sugar)
- Click the "***Schedule System Index***" button (and confirm the performance-related javascript alert, if any), after that a pop-up window with a list will appear
- Scroll down in the pop-up window and select "***Delete existing data when index is performed. Only data in the selected modules will be indexed.***".
  **This step is important**. If you forget to select this checkbox, the re-index will fail (because it tries to refill an existing index, rather than re-creating it from scratch).
- Confirm by clicking on the "***Index***" button. This will (re)create the index you need.
- Now you should be able to install new modules again!

**Notes:**

- The name of the Elasticsearch index is based on the value of `$sugar_config['unique_key']` in `config.php`. Changing this value and rebuilding the cache will result in Sugar looking for a new index name. You'll have to trigger a reindex as described above (unless you somehow rename the index in Elasticsearch, so that it will be found again).
- The newly created index will possibly remain empty (which should be enough for module installs though) unless your cron/Schedulers are running. If the Elastic Search Scheduler is running it will fill the index with data within the next minutes/hours and you can use the search on the top right of Sugar.
- If you have access to the server's host-system, you can also choose to re-create the Index from the command-line:
  `bin/sugarcrm search:silent_reindex --clearData` (slow, only runs on single cpu core) or 
  `bin/sugarcrm search:silent_reindex_mp --clearData` (fast, can use several cpu cores)
  The file `bin/sugarcrm` must have executable permissions for this.
  (The first and single-threaded way may also work by prefixing `php`  instead)
  The last - or possibly both - commands may not be available if your Sugar version is very outdated.

Comment: Any idea why an index would disappear and how to prevent it from happening in the first place?

Comment: ES Indices usually don't "disappear" unless you rename the config's `unique_key` (then Sugar will look for the index under a different name) or if you did a clean reinstall of ElasticSearch. However, Index corruptions do happen sometimes, in my experience. But still very rarely and usually with weird and unpredictable issues, so I wouldn't know how to prevent them to begin with. If you run into broken Indices repeatedly, try to understand the error (e.g. breaking ES field number/length limit) and see if you can adjust Sugar's Modules/Fields/Search-settings or ES' config to fix the issue.